# Shared Preferences only finding first entry in list

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to display some subtraction questions on a "report activity."

When I just use bundles and "getIntExtra" it works fine, and I get all of the questions.

However, when I comment that code out and make a SharedPReferences class, and use the same structure with "shared preferences," the questions get added to the array and it seems added to the list, but the "list size"  is one.

I'm wondering why the commented out code uses the correct list size, but getting the same stuff from the SharedPreferences doesn't (and why all my attempts to clear the lists don't seem to work; the one question listed is always the same one; I fear there's an ever-growing collection of these questions).

```
int numQuestions = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".numQuestions", 0);

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Num Questions: " + numQuestions);
       // this gives me ONE even though         
    for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; ++i)
    {
        int minuendAnswer =prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".minuendAnswer" + i, 0);
         // more of these 


        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Minuend Answer: " + minuendAnswer);


        // add to list
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("Question #: " + (i+1) + '\n');
        str.append("Subtrahend, minuend, and difference answers: "
        + minuendAnswer + " - " + subtrahendAnswer + " = " + differenceAnswer + '\n');
        str.append("Subtrahend, minuend, and difference Responses: "
                + minuendResponse + " - " + subtrahendResponse + " = " + differenceResponse + '\n');

        listItems.add(str.toString());
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), " ListItems List Size: " + listItems.size()); 

    }

    /*
     * 
     *           bundling part
     * 
     * int numQuestions = getIntent().getIntExtra(getPackageName() + ".numQuestions", 0);

    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Num Questions: " + numQuestions);

    for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; ++i)
    {
        int minuendAnswer = getIntent().getIntExtra(getPackageName() + ".minuendAnswer" + i, 0);
         // and some more of those


        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Minuend Answer: " + minuendAnswer);
         // and some more of those
        // add to list
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("Question #: " + (i+1) + '\n');
        str.append("Subtrahend, minuend, and difference answers: "
        + minuendAnswer + " - " + subtrahendAnswer + " = " + differenceAnswer + '\n');
        str.append("Subtrahend, minuend, and difference Responses: "
                + minuendResponse + " - " + subtrahendResponse + " = " + differenceResponse + '\n');

        listItems.add(str.toString());



    }
    */ 


private void putQuestionsPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences state = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);  

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = state.edit();

    editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".numQuestions", labelQuestions.size());
     Log.i("sp editor says numQ is:  ", Integer.toString( labelQuestions.size())); 

    int i = 0;
    for(Iterator<LabelTestQuestion> it = labelQuestions.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        LabelTestQuestion tmp = it.next();
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".minuendAnswer" + i, tmp.getMinuendAnswer());
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".subtrahendAnswer" + i, tmp.getSubtrahendAnswer());
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".differenceAnswer" + i, tmp.getDifferenceAnswer());
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".minuendResponse" + i, tmp.getMinuendResponse());
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".subtrahendResponse" + i, tmp.getSubtrahendResponse());
        editor.putInt(getPackageName() + ".differenceResponse" + i, tmp.getDifferenceResponse());

        ++i;   // remember that, my dear ;) 

    }

    editor.commit();      
}private void getQuestionsPreferences() {
    labelQuestions.clear();

    // Get Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences prefState = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 

    // get test questions from the shared preferences

    int numQuestions = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".numQuestions", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; ++i)
    {
        labelq = new LabelTestQuestion();

        // get the test question data
        int minuendAnswer = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".minuendAnswer" +i, 0);
        int subtrahendAnswer = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".subtrahendAnswer" +i, 0);
        int differenceAnswer = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".differenceAnswer" +i, 0);
        int minuendResponse = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".minuendResponse" +i, 0);
        int subtrahendResponse = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".subtrahendResponse" +i, 0);
        int differenceResponse = prefState.getInt(getPackageName() + ".differenceResponse" +i, 0);

        labelq.setMinuendAnswer(minuendAnswer);
        labelq.setSubtrahendAnswer(subtrahendAnswer);
        labelq.setDifferenceAnswer(differenceAnswer);
        labelq.setMinuendResponse(minuendResponse);
        labelq.setSubtrahendResponse(subtrahendResponse);
        labelq.setDifferenceResponse(differenceResponse);

        labelQuestions.add(labelq);
    }


};
```

Comment: Under getPreferences, when I ask what the array size is, I'm told 0. I'm thinking that might be where the problem is.

Comment: Hmmm... other examples with sharedPreferences seem to still have to have putExtra.   Since my directions said I was "replacing" doing it by bundles, I thought I could leave that out.  I think it's working now...

Comment: ... or not.   Back to apparent redundancy...